# Sync Project with Gradle icon missing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android Studio. I am currently following this tutorial by Google. They seem to have a Sync Project with Gradle icon option. But I can't find that in my Android Studio.

Their icons(https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/#4):
[image]

I can only see this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` from the menubar.

I can also find that icon on the basic toolbar:

[image]

If it is not there for you, you can restore it from the settings `File -> Settings -> Menus and Toolbars` :

[image]

Comment: I went to the setting as you asked me to, now what do I do? I tried to click on that arrow sign which said restore all selected files, but nothing happens.

Comment: Go to the Andoid.Main.ToolBarActionGroup folder, click the '+' icon, then Add action. Search for Sync Project with Gradle Files, and click OK.

Comment: I followed your instructions, Sync Project with Gradle Files appears under Andoid.Main.ToolBarActionGroup. But, it still doesn't seem that Sync Project with Gradle Files doesn't appear in Files.

Comment: Maybe try the Restore All Defaults option, and do not forget to reopen the Android Studio after each modification. If the icon still not be shown then try to search for Android Studio update, this is all i can help. At worst you need to stick with the File -> Sync option.

Comment: I figured it out. I was using the wrong file all along, thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate the solution in the comments, for other people who stumble onto this page.

The `Sync Project with Gradle Files` option only appears if there is a `settings.gradle` file in the root directory.

If you are like me, and like to open an entire repo, and have the project as a subdirectory, you will need to go to `File->Project Structure...`, then, under `Project Settings`, click `Modules`, click `+` (Add), then import the directory that your `settings.gradle` file is in.